# ES6 arrow / function equivalency

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm just getting around to changing some of my code to ES6 and I ran across some code where the arrow function did not work and I am not sure I understand why. The code is from a plugin for Hapi to decorate the `reply` interface.

ES5:

```
server.decorate('reply', 'test', function(schema, response) {
  return this.response(mask(schema, response));
});
```

ES6:

```
server.decorate('reply', 'test', (schema, response) => {
  return this.response(mask(schema, response));
});
```

The E66 doesn't work and throws an error:

```
Uncaught error: this.response is not a function
```

Why is this?

Comment: the arrow functions in ES6 automatically binds `this` to the outer scope, so it's not equivalent in this case.

Comment: I see - what wound be the answer? just leave it as `function`?

Comment: Yes. There's not a lot you can do if `this` for that particular function is bound to something else.

Comment: Ok. Post an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks

Comment: The difference in `this` behavior is in the very first paragraph of the relevant MDN page. By the way, correct terminology is "arrow function" (not "double arrow function").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case, the library is changing what `this` refers to inside the callback for `decorate`. When using arrow functions (`=>`), `this` is equivalent to the `this` of the outer scope. This means that you're basically stuck using `function` for this.